# Script shell that modify Java class

Tags: java, string, shell, variables, sh

My question is explicit : is it possible to create a shell script that is able to edit a java class.

What I want to do is to modify string variable value running this script.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible - it's all just bytes isn't it? The more pertinent question is **why** would you ever want to do this?

Comment: How can I do ? My variable is just an URL : String URLNODE = "http://192.168.2.30:5555/wd/hub";

Comment: 1) Create a properties file. 2) Put the value into the properties file. 3) Read the properties file rather than hardcoding variables in the code. 4) Write whatever you want to the properties file in your script.

Comment: Or 1) read the [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) to determine the [binary structure of a class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html). 2) write a script to modify that structure. 3) pray you haven't corrupted the file format.

Comment: Now: **which sounds simpler**?

Comment: Ahah may be the first one ! Thank you for putting me back on track :)

Comment: Or pass the parameter on the command line.

Comment: how can you do that ?